# XML parsers for C++ which convert xml nodes to C++ objects

Tags: c++, xml, deserialization

Ive a requirement to parse a XML file, and create a tree of nodes inside my application, which then will be used for other purposes like searching and stuff.

The node structure is homogeneous in nature, i.e it will have only a few fields/attricutes like 1.Id 2.Data 3.Children.Even the xml node will be similar, i.e id, data and children

Can anyone help me with which library should I use so as to create something like this??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very very easy one to use is mini xml (abbreviated to mxml)

http://www.minixml.org/

Answer (score 4):

A very good library for this is [Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/property_tree.html). Look at this example of how to use it with XML:
► http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/tutorial.html

The property tree itself is agnostic of the XML file. If you do this right, your objects will also be agnostic of XML, which makes your code more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm normally using libxml2 for this - admittedly it's C, but does create a tree of objects.